# MySQL Query with UNIXTIME

Tags: mysql

I need help with query that changes current value of unix time to normal date, and raplace it in row. This must be done for all users at once.

this is example that changes unixtime to regular:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME('1531180800','%Y-%m-%d')
```

I made something like that for test for 1 sepcific user:

```
UPDATE core_pfields_content SET field_16 = (SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME((SELECT field_16 FROM core_pfields_content WHERE member_id = 3930),'%Y-%m-%d')) WHERE member_id = 3930
```

but it throws error:

> [Err] 1093 - You can't specify target table 'core_pfields_content' for update in FROM clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You realy can't specify target table 'core_pfields_content' for update in FROM clause, because you use it into subquery

But in your case you can do this like in code below:

```
UPDATE core_pfields_content SET field_16 = FROM_UNIXTIME(field_16, '%Y-%m-%d') WHERE member_id = 3930
```

You don't need subquery for this